# copy file from /root/storage/emulated/0 fails on android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, file-copying, nononsense-filepicker

I am trying to copy files from a location on the device to the app folder, and using:

```
public static void copyFile(final String srcAbsolutePath, final String dstAbsolutePath) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream srcFileStream = null;
        FileOutputStream dstFileStream = null;
        try {
            srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(srcAbsolutePath);
            dstFileStream = new FileOutputStream(dstAbsolutePath);
            byte[] writeBytes = new byte[1024];

            int bytesCount;
            while ((bytesCount = srcFileStream.read(writeBytes)) > 0) {
                dstFileStream.write(writeBytes, 0, bytesCount);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy the file from src="+srcAbsolutePath+" to="+dstAbsolutePath, ex);
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            // close the streams
            if (srcFileStream != null) {
                srcFileStream.close();
            }

            if (dstFileStream != null) {
                dstFileStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

and I am running into this error:

```
Failed to copy the file from src=/root/storage/emulated/0/TestApp/1a5e67e1-c166-4a52-abb4-3de61898e109.pdf to=/data/user/0/com.myapp.package/files/78e6a56b-3141-4024-a3a1-f3f44ccc6dfb.pdf
                                                                      java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/storage/emulated/0/TestApp/1a5e67e1-c166-4a52-abb4-3de61898e109.pdf (Permission denied)
```

I have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am using https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker to pick the file (Uri).

I have the following in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/nnf_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Well, that should be an invalid path on most Android devices, so I am not surprised that it is crashing. You need to figure out why that library is giving you that value. None of the code in your question has anything to do with that, though.

Comment: make sure that the file dose exists, you have `java.io.FileNotFoundException` warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found an utility in NoNonsense-FilePicker (getFileForUri):

https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/nononsenseapps/filepicker/Utils.java